# How to install Linux & Windows on a Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, unix

I've been contemplating on buying a Macbook Pro, but what I want to try and do is to have Linux, Windows and Mac (Primary) running on the Macbook. I feel this is a good idea for me, as I'm in my first year of Computer Science in Uni, so I would like to get a serious feel for Linux and Mac, as I've been using mostly just Windows up until now. As well as the fact, I can carry the Macbook about and so forth.

I'm a bit of a newbie still when it comes to Macs, but shouldn't be a problem picking up on things. I have just been looking at different ways to install all three Operating systems, some use Virtual Machine, whilst others opt for partitioning the hard drive.

I basically want to know which method would be most fluid for me, as well as what precautions I should take should anything go wrong. I need to have it running smoothly, especially since a lot of important work will be on it.

Comment: You should look around for BootCamp. This will solve your Windows bootable part, dualboot. What do you need linux for? If it's small and just for testing purposes you could use VMWare for that - and backup the .vmdk-file so you always can start with a clean copy if you mess it up. Linux can also be booted from an USB. (Check "Ubuntu Live USB" for this)

Comment: [This](http://lifehacker.com/5531037/how-to-triple+boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-boot-camp-required) guide is from long back. Not definitely sure if it is *still* relevant. Should be useful nevertheless.

Comment: Regarding Linux - OSX is based upon UNIX and thus shares many similarities with Linux. For your computer science course you may find many things (especially involving terminal work) are the same or very similar between OSX and Linux thus negating the need to install Linux at all. For network stack uses a virtual machine will probably suffice.

Answer (score 1):

For windows you can install it in bootcamp is very easy because there are a lot of videos or tutorials in youtube for this job.

[image]

[Install Windows With Bootcamp](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2S5YM-TQ-nc)

For linux you can install Parallels.

[image: Parallels]

[Install Linux With Parallels](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NITES7KDLoo)

Virtual-Box.

[image: Virtual-Box]

[Install Linux With VirtualBox](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WiiswmOH1Q)

Or VMWARE.

[image: WMWARE]

[Install Linux With WMWare WorkStation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFrqWtTnhOU)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O40UG1guLeo without rEFIt
and here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1564943 with rEFIt

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked pages change.